# Heroku multiple build-time config vars

Tags: docker, heroku, environment-variables

## Context

Hi! I have multiple Heroku apps deployed by the same repository on github. The only difference is that they have different build args, as defined in my Dockerfile:

```
ARG REACT_APP_ENV
```

## Problem

I thought of using heroku's [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), but [they are not available at build-time](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml#setting-build-time-environment-variables).
The problem with using the heroku build-time config vars on `heroku.yml` is that I want it to be different depending on the heroku app (also I don't want to write them on the code or push them to github).

How can I set multiple build-time config vars depending on the app?

Answer (score 1):

As of the time of this answer, there is no way to obtain config vars at build time, so the solution would be to build the image locally.